# Jquery code to select value in input box not

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to build a data table that shows some results when parameter values are picked . I started with building a label ,input box and button. I am starting to test trying to retrieve the value entered into the text box.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#search').submit(function() {
        var id  = $('#sun').val();
    });  
});
```

```html
<div id="page-title">
    <h2>sun Details</h2>   
</div>
<div class="panel-box col-sm-5">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-md-3 control-label">Please enter a sun Number</label>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="sun" placeholder="xxx">   
        </div>
        <button class="btn btn-blue-alt" id="search" type="submit">Search</button>
    </div>             
</div>
```

Comment: what is your question? what do you need help with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.submit()` is for forms.  If you are not using a form, use `.click()` or `$('#selector').on('click', function(){});`.   [Example](https://jsfiddle.net/atg5m6ym/6754/).

If you are going to use a form, the selector for `.submit` needs to be the form element.